# How to include html tags within a wordpress excerpt?

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, hyperlink

Currently in a wordpress template, if you use the code `the_excerpt()` it will display the first 55 words of a post and strips all html from the post.

I need to include `<a href...` tags in the excerpt so that links are still visible.

Existing methods include:

1. Hacking the wordpress core - definitely not an option.
2. using a plugin - don't want to use, it's dependent on the developer keeping the plugin up to date
3. writing code within functions.php to re-write the excerpt filter. - I'd prefer not to use this as it might have to be changed in future versions of WP

Is there a filter hook or other known method to include html easily without hacks?

All help is appreciated!
Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I see it, you can only use method 2 and 3; both of them can be updated via WordPress' back-end with virtually no programming required which is ideal if you're going to be installing and using them on client sites.

Here's a tutorial with working code for method 3 -- http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/ and here's a plugin to use method 2 -- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/

Comment: The plugin for method 2 hasn't been updated in 2 years.  Wondering if it's still current.

Comment: @Steve -- Since my answer was posted three years ago, probably not. http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-custom-auto-excerpt/ or http://wordpress.org/plugins/sem-fancy-excerpt/ that might be able to do a similar job if you tried installing the other plugin and it didn't work on your version of WordPress.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following statement sometimes to get the first 55 words of a post content.

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', get_the_content()), 0, 55));
```

Comment: This uses a completely different field.

Comment: Finally someone with a practical and easy solution for this issue.. Thanks.

Comment: This can potentially trim in-between opening and closing tags, resulting in invalid HTML. also, it will display less than 55 words because it counts tags as words